# Multiple t-tests against a single control condition. Is this correct?

Tags: t-test, group-differences

I have a control condition **A** and several other conditions (**B**, **C**, **D**, etc.) against which I want to test **A** for differences (i.e. **A** vs **B**, **A** vs **C**, **A** vs **D**, etc.).

Is it correct to run:

> ttest(**A**, **B**);
>
> ttest(**A**, **C**);
>
> ttest(**A**, **D**);

and treat them separetely?

Thank you very much.

Comment: For comparing many groups against one control group, you can perform an ANOVA followed by a post-hoc mean comparison using [Dunnett's adjustment](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2281208). Most common statistical software packages allow that option.

Comment: Such version (control vs each treatment) of multiple t-test exists: [Dunnett's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunnett's_test). It is a multiple comparison test, i.e. it penalizes for the number of comparisons.